# Toggling edit mode for many layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, editing

How do I toggle the edit mode for many layers with QGIS 3.16 and PostGIS layers? Maybe there is a plugin or a function in the UI.

I don't want to select each layer and switch the edit mode separately.

When I select some layers and use the *toggle edit mode* function, only one of the layers switches its mode.

Comment: But you can only edit one layer at a time - so why toggle editing for a bunch of them?

Comment: Have a look at https://oslandia.com/en/2017/10/10/undo-redo-stack-is-back-qgis-transaction-groups/  ( "Users can switch all the layers in edit mode at once. A real time saver.")

Comment: Thanks, this project option was unknown for me. Maybe that will help, because my users have to work with very complex situations with features from dozens of layers. And within a short time they have to update or insert features from many of this layers.

Answer (score 5):

You can loop through layers you want to enable editing for and toggle editing in the Python console.

```py
for lyr in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if lyr.name() in ['layer 1', 'layer 2', 'layer 3']:
        lyr.startEditing()
```

You could leave out the `if` to toggle editing for all layers, or use

```py
lyr.name() not in ['layer 4' , 'layer 5']
```

if there are only a few you don't want to toggle editing on for

Comment: Yes, of course that is possible. But I was searching for a solution for "non-professional" users.

Comment: Then please be more specific in your question. Nowhere do you mention "non-professional users".

Comment: Yes, you are right. sorry. I edited the question now.